# Problema al traducir página mediante PHP

Tags: php, html, traducción

He conseguido llegar a traducir una página web de ejemplo mediante una array, el problema que he encontrado es que al pulsar el botón(se usa para traducir) te dirige hacia el index , y yo lo que quiero es que se traduzca la página donde te encuentras.
Os dejo el código además de alguna imagen:

```
<div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>"><?php echo $lang['home'] ?></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>index.php?page=about"><?php echo $lang['about'] ?></a>
                    </li>

                    <?php 
                        include('menu.php');
                    ?>
                    
                    <li class="right">
                        <a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>index.php?lang=es"><?php echo $lang['español'] ?></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="right">
                        <a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>index.php?lang=ct"><?php echo $lang['catalan'] ?></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="right">
                        <a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>index.php?lang=en"><?php echo $lang['english'] ?></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

https://ibb.co/w62zkDM

No se como realizarlo de otra forma, tampoco se si se podrá lo que estoy intentando hacer , las traducciones las tengo en una única carpeta.
Un saludo.

Comment: En todos los casos tú estás redirigiendo a `index.php` al poner: `<a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>index.php?...`, ¿a dónde tendría que redigirir o qué tendría que hacer?

Comment: Que se traduzca la página donde te encuentras.

Comment: Con solo poner el parametro en el href deberia valerte.
Ej:
<a href="?lang=en"><?php echo $lang['english'] ?></a>

Comment: No funciona , me sigue mandando al index se queda así: index.php?lang=en.No entiendo porque no puedo